# Where are X,Y Coordinates measured from in PHP GD Library?

Tags: php, gd

I've written a class in PHP for cropping an image and it works. The thing is I don't understand the maths. The best way to show you how it works is probably via image.

What I don't understand is that when using [`imagecopyresampled()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) in PHP what is actually used as the reference point for the x and y variables for the source image.

I assumed at first that it was the centre of the image, thus meaning that the absolute center = y/2 and x/2. That worked for the y value but not x. I calculated x from the left side of the resampling area.

```
(source y - resamplearea y) / 2
```

It appears to me that there are two different reference points. I read the associated documentation in the PHP manual, but I can't find anything about reference points.

Is it referenced from the bottom left corner? If so, why did I have to work that out for myself?

Small example snip:

```
imagecopyresampled($outputImage, $this->tempImage, 0, 0, $this->src_x, $this->src_y, $this->outputx, $this->outputy, $this->inputImageWidth, $this->inputImageHeight);
```

Am I missing something?

[image: JPEG Sampling]

Comment: The reference point is 0 pixels left and top, so the top left corner

Comment: Strange because it doesn't seem to be the case for me. Does that mean that the top left = 0 for y? Because in order for my code to work it either must be referencing the bottom left or everything south of the top left corner is in a negative direction. My code works perfectly it's just a bit strange that there is not a clear answer anywhere. Surely it is in the manual?

Comment: are you sure that you call the arguments in the right order? Can you paste some code?

Comment: I'm fairly sure. Have a look at the code snip I added.

Comment: it seems that you switch source and destination?

Comment: Top-left is `(0, 0)` and bottom right is `(width, heigth)`

Comment: Bottom-right is (width-1, height-1). Otherwise, on a 1x1 image, there would be 4 different sets of coordinates mapped to the same pixel. :)